# SwiftUI macOS cannot change main menu when a NavigationView is present

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I try to change some items of the main menu in my SwiftUI macOS app. I don't have macOS Catalyst yet, where the UIKit and UIMenuBuilder comes into play. I want to create my app for macOS versions below Catalyst as well.

I added an AppDelegate where I want to change the main menu by removing certain entries and add a key shortcut to the edit > delete command.

Everything works fine until I add a NavigationView to the view stack:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let mainMenu = NSApplication.shared.mainMenu
        
        // this works
        mainMenu!.removeItem(mainMenu!.item(withTitle: "File")!)
        mainMenu!.item(withTitle: "Help")!.isHidden = true
        
        // the following lines have no effect
        let key = String(utf16CodeUnits: [unichar(NSBackspaceCharacter)], count: 1) as String
        let del = mainMenu!.item(withTitle: "Edit")!.submenu!.item(withTitle: "Delete")
        del!.keyEquivalent = key
        del!.keyEquivalentModifierMask = NSEvent.ModifierFlags.command
        del!.action = #selector(foobar)
        
        // no item is added to Edit menu
        let newItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Foobar", action: #selector(foobar), keyEquivalent: "D")
        mainMenu!.item(withTitle: "Edit")!.submenu!.addItem(newItem)
    }
    
    @objc func foobar() {
        print("foobar")
    }
}

@main
struct testApp: App {
    #if os(macOS)
        @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    #endif
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                Text("hi")
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 200, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

When you remove the NavigationView in testApp and only Show Text("hi"), all commands from my AppDelegate work well.
However, when you have a NavigationView somewhere in your UI, the `.removeItem` and `.isHidden = true` still work, but the rest does not.

Why does having a NavigationView somewhere in your UI (it doesn't have to be the top one, can also be more layers between) enable me to add a key shortcut to a menu item?
Is this a bug? If yes, is this a known bug? If no, why is it happening?

Should I build the main menu completely on my own instead of using the default one created by the app?

Answer (score 0):

NavigationView seems to try to build its own menu system while it's being set up, especially around Edit menu, so it looks like our own update is being overriden by them.

If it's updated deliberately later on with the NavigationView modifier, then your code should be working out.

```
       NavigationView {
            List (selection: self.$selection){
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in    
               ...
                }            
                .onChange(of: selection) { _ in
                    if (!menuUpdated) {
                        print("MENU UPDATED!! ")
                        let mainMenu = NSApplication.shared.mainMenu
                        let key = String(utf16CodeUnits: [unichar(NSBackspaceCharacter)], count: 1) as String
                        let del = mainMenu!.item(withTitle: "Edit")!.submenu!.item(withTitle: "Delete")
                        del!.keyEquivalent = key
                        del!.keyEquivalentModifierMask = NSEvent.ModifierFlags.command
//                        mainMenu!.item(withTitle: "View")!.submenu!.addItem(withTitle:"Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "x")
                        menuUpdated = true
                    }
                }
```

Now you can delete an item in the list with a keyboard shortcut.